# how to keep the first link of each accordion open while having two copies of the same accordion in the same page

Tags: jquery

I am a beginner in jquery. Below is the code I came up with for a basic accordion with the help of a tutorial:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           $('.reAccord > .accTitle').each(function(index){
               $('.accContainer').hide();   
               $('.accTitle:first').next().slideDown();
               $(this).click(function() {
                    if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
                        $('.accTitle').next().slideUp();
                        $(this).next().slideDown();
                    }
                    return false;

                   });
           });

        });
```

but the problem is if i duplicate the html to have two seperate accordions in the same page only the first element in accordion 1 is active while first link in accordion two is collapsed. what changes should i make to keep the first link of each seperate copy of accordion open. and also i have to use the **.each(function(index){});** in this  :

```
 <!-- accordion 1 -->
        <div class="reAccord">
            <h2 class="accTitle"><a href="#">Accordion one</a></h2>
            <div class="accContainer">
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac                    turpis egestas.</p>
            </div>
            <h2 class="accTitle"><a href="#">Accordion Two</a></h2>
            <div class="accContainer">
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac                    turpis egestas.</p>
            </div>
            <h2 class="accTitle"><a href="#">Accordion Three</a></h2>
            <div class="accContainer">
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac                    turpis egestas.</p>
            </div>
            <h2 class="accTitle"><a href="#">Accordion Four</a></h2>
            <div class="accContainer">
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac                    turpis egestas.</p>
            </div>
        </div> <!--reaccord-->
        <!-- accordion 2 -->
        <div class="reAccord">
            <h2 class="accTitle"><a href="#">Accordion one</a></h2>
            <div class="accContainer">
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac                    turpis egestas.</p>
            </div>
            <h2 class="accTitle"><a href="#">Accordion Two</a></h2>
            <div class="accContainer">
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac                    turpis egestas.</p>
            </div>
            <h2 class="accTitle"><a href="#">Accordion Three</a></h2>
            <div class="accContainer">
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac                    turpis egestas.</p>
            </div>
            <h2 class="accTitle"><a href="#">Accordion Four</a></h2>
            <div class="accContainer">
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac                    turpis egestas.</p>
            </div>
        </div> <!--reaccord-->
```

Comment: FYI, if you're not making an accordian for the sake of making an accordian, you can use https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: you have nothing to define one accordion from the other as far as your script is concerned - add some ID's and names to your accordion containers, include them in the jQuery selector and then make a control for each accordion. and yeah, use jQuery-UI : don't reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('.reAccord').each(function(index){
    $el = $(this);
       $(this).find('.accTitle').each(function(index){
           $(this).next('.accContainer').hide();   
           $el.find('.accTitle:first').next().slideDown();
           $(this).click(function() {
                if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
                    $(this).parent().find('.accContainer').slideUp();
                    $(this).next('.accContainer').slideDown();
                }
                return false;

               });
       });

    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6Lnnw6jd/1/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the super fast response... still the first link of the first accordion is the only thing that is open... rest are not working :(

Comment: hey, thats great works like a charm... can you explain the code a little bit so i can understand what it does... especially the line `$el = $(this);`. Btw thanks for the help

Comment: $el is used to save the current selection of the .reAccord class you can remove this if you like and target all the .reAccord elements like this: https://jsfiddle.net/6Lnnw6jd/2/

Comment: is it like a variable